# Shell script for remote SSH

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, ssh

I'm new to `shell` scripts, and I have `centos` running. I want to write a shell script that `ssh` a remote machine and execute a bunch of commands. The problem I'm facing is how to provide the username, the password, the remote machine address, and the private access key to a command that shall connect the remote machine.

I've Google'd and found some scripts, but all of them need a utility called `expect`, and I don't want to install any utility, only to run my script. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You can login automatically using a [public key](http://www.ece.uci.edu/~chou/ssh-key.html).

Comment: ssh public keys is the "correct" way to do this as Victor Hugo already suggested. That aside: expect is a fairly old, popular and well-established utility, are there any reasons you don't want to install it?

Comment: yes cuz of only one script don't want to install any utility. i will have to convinced network guys for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass all you need in a `ssh` call, doing the following:

```
ssh -i private_key_path user_name@remote_machine "command"
```

If you're going to use this connection many times, and want to maintain it configured, add the following lines to you `.ssh/config` file:

```
Host host_alias
    User user_name
    HostName remote_machine
    IdentityFile private_key_path
```

and then access the remote machine, and execute the command you want, by doing:

```
ssh host_alias "command"
```

Notice that command, AFAIK, must be embraced in quotes, as it must be considered as only **one** argument by `ssh`.